# HTTP Socket API on iPhone

Tags: iphone, http, rest

For my project course I'm thinking to develop an application in iPhone. I have some objective-c knowledge but I don't know what kind of API's Apple provide.

I've implemented RESTful web service and I was wondering if there is a way to access features of this RESTful API via iPhone. I mean, what kind of API's area available to send HTTP GET, POST, ... and to process JSON/XML data returned by web service?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650700/restful-iphone-client-and-model-hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All HTTP request methods (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, etc…) are available with [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can parse XML with [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and you can parse JSON with [JSON-Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) (it's really good).

Comment: beat me to it ;) +1 don't forget you can use a NSDictionary to pick data out of the JSON response!

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial may be helpful: [Tutorial: Simple iPhone Rest Client](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/tutorial-simple-iphone-rest-client)

Answer (score 0):

A great and widely accepted API for HTTP requests/etc is ASIHTTPRequest, here is the [link](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). As far as XML parsing, you might want to take at the Apple provided `NSXMLParser` (note there could be external APIs for this, but I am unaware of them). Here is its class [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)